# remove white space from text in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm try to put some text into an element's class attribute. In the example below {{operator}} will always have a value.

```
<input type="radio" class="ng-hide test-{{operator}}"
```

Sometime though the value of {{operator}} can contain white space or be two words.

Something like: (although this doesn't work)

```
  <input type="radio" class="ng-hide test-{{operator.replace("","-")}}"
```

How can I replace the white space with a hyphen or replace it with an empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `operator.replace(' ','-')` or `operator.replace(/\s+/g, '-')` (regex version by @Tushar)

Working sample below, checkout class of input via browser's developer tools

```js
angular.module('app', []).run(function($rootScope){
  $rootScope.operator = 'my style';
});
angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<input class="input" type="radio" class="test-{{operator.replace(' ','-')}}"/> 

<p>Operator is: {{operator}}</p>
<p>Class is: test-{{operator.replace(' ','-')}}</p>
```